# Delays in VideoLan with WPF playing 8 simultaneous streams

Tags: c#, .net, video, video-streaming, vlc

I tried to ask this same question in the Codeplex discussion but that forum is nearly dead.

I have a WPF application that displays eight H264 camera video streams simultaneously. I used the control and almost all is perfect.

I am having a problem when I start running the application, sometimes the application starts awkwardly (the videos are not fluid as if they had very low FPS, I can not interact with the UI thread smoothly, etc ...). Other times, when I start running, everything is smoothly with no delays in the videos, UI thread responds instantly, etc... About 80% of the times the application starts perfect.

I have no idea what it may be, I've done several tests, such as starting the videos from different threads or even delaying a second time between the start of the videos, without success.

I am using the following properties:

```
VlcContext.StartupOptions.AddOption("--no-video-title-show"); 
VlcContext.StartupOptions.AddOption("--ffmpeg-hw"); 
VlcContext.StartupOptions.AddOption("--network-caching=300");
```

I wish I could solve the problem, or else I wish I could detect when it happens to reset the application without the user interaction.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to detect the problem as showing the console I have not seen anything relevant, and if I try to access the FPS control property always returns 0.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thank you

PD: The computer is a Intel Core i7 with 8GB of RAM. 
The CPU is around 37% when displaying all the streams.

Comment: Windows is not a realtime OS.  You're kicking off several latency-sensitive processes at once.  Things can vary due to what's in disk cache, other processes running, etc.  If this is an application that is to _stay_ running long-term, is this a problem?  I doubt you have a code issue, just a expectations issue.  You could always throw more hardware at it.  SSDs are good for startup performance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The device is also equipped with an SSD. 
I realize that maybe I'm expecting too much, but It seems that if I start running the application, once it starts well it seems that does not degrade the performance anymore. 
Also, I have an external application that allows me to close the application and when it detects that the process is dead it starts it again. Running this application I see how the application can start well 10 times, then start wrong twice and then in the next restart, start running fine again.